# Firebase Firestore not allowing LinkedHashMaps to be stored - Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing a few custom objects in my firebase firestore db, no problem in adding them to a document, and I can in fact check from the console they are there, they've maintained their structure and they're good to go.

However, when I try to retrieve the class I use:

`val class = snapshot.toObject(Class::class.java)`

I get an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method projectname.setFieldsHashMap argument 1 has type java.util.LinkedHashMap, got java.util.HashMap

I looked around and found nothing, read in a couple places that firestore doesn't order items, but never read that firestore explicitly doesn't allow LinkedHashMaps. One last thing, when I view the document in firestore all forms of Maps go under the name Maps, it doesn't specify which type so I did feel like it was ignoring the order already when uploading, I just don't see anyone with the same problem.

I changed all my LinkedHashMaps to HashMaps and it worked, so before changing everything in my code to account for this, it would be great to get a confirmation or any insight into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkedHashMap isn't really an accurate data type for Firestore object fields.  LinkedHashMap imposes an order on the entries in the map.  However, Firestore does not impose any order on the properties of map type field.  So, if you wrote all the entries from a LinkedHashMap into a Firestore object, then read it back out, you would lose all the ordering.  As such, you should use a HashMap, since that represents a simple set of key/value pairs without order.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I didn't get back to you, but thanks for the confirmation! I converted everything to Hashmaps of <Int, HashMap<String,String>> and then used the Int value to get the order I'm interested in